# select the first item in dropdown when there is only one item, and disable the dropdown primeng

Tags: angular, dropdown, primeng

If I have the following dropdown, how can I select the first item if there is only 1 element in the `filteredGroupNames` then disable the dropdown and don't display the `placeholder`

```
<ng-template pTemplate="content">
    <div class="field">
      <label>Name</label>
      <p-dropdown [(ngModel)]="newOrSelectedGroupName" [options]="filteredGroupNames" [showClear]="true"
                  placeholder="Select a group"

      ></p-dropdown>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `optionDisabled` is an available attribute for PrimeNG dropdowns. You can set it to be conditionally disabled based on the length of `filteredGroupNames`. Something like the following:

```
<p-dropdown [(ngModel)]="newOrSelectedGroupName" 
            [options]="filteredGroupNames" [showClear]="true"
           placeholder="Select a group"
            [optionDisabled]="filteredGroupNames.length > 1 ? 'inactive' : 'active'"
></p-dropdown>
```

Comment: Yes but what about pre-selecting the first item when there is only one in `filteredGroupNames `

Answer (score 0):

In your `component.html` file

```
<ng-template pTemplate="content">
    <div class="field">
      <label>Name</label>
      <p-dropdown [(ngModel)]="newOrSelectedGroupName" [options]="filteredGroupNames"
             [showClear]="filteredGroupNames.length!=1" placeholder="Select a group" [class.disabled]="filteredGroupNames.length==1"
      ></p-dropdown>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
```

In your `component.ts file`

```
newOrSelectedGroupName;
ngOnInit():void {

  if(filteredGroupNames.lengh==1) {
    this.newOrSelectedGroupName=filteredGroupNames[0].value;
  }
}
```

I have assumed the `value` key is present in the object `filteredGroupNames` and it is binded as value to the dropdown in your HTML like `optionValue="value"`.

Sample object is

```
filteredGroupNames = [
  {
    name:'name 1',
    value:1
  }
];
```

In your `styles.scss` or `styles.css`

```
.disabled .p-dropdown-panel,
.disabled .p-dropdown-trigger {
  display: none;
}

.disabled.p-inputwrapper-focus .p-dropdown {
  border-color: #ced4da !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So what I ended up doing is:

```
<ng-template pTemplate="content">
    <div class="field">
      <label>Name</label>
      <p-dropdown [(ngModel)]="newOrSelectedGroupName" [options]="filteredGroupNames" [showClear]="filteredGroupNames.length !== 1"
                  [optionValue]="getOptionValue()"
                  placeholder="Select a group"
                  pTooltip="There is only one name available to select!"
                  [tooltipDisabled]="filteredGroupNames.length !== 1"
                  [disabled]="filteredGroupNames.length === 1"
      ></p-dropdown>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
```

and in the ts file:

```
getOptionValue(): string {
    if (this.filteredGroupNames.length === 1) {
      const firstName = this.filteredGroupNames[0];
      this.newOrSelectedGroupName = firstName;
      return firstName;
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

p-dropdown will select the first value if no placeholder are set, so an easy way to achieve the asked behavior is to put a conditional placeholder

```
<p-dropdown [(ngModel)]="newOrSelectedGroupName" [options]="filteredGroupNames" [showClear]="filteredGroupNames.length !== 1"
            [optionValue]="getOptionValue()"
            placeholder="filteredGroupNames.length === 1 ? '' : 'Select a group'"
            [disabled]="filteredGroupNames.length === 1"
  ></p-dropdown>
```

This way, if only one option exists, no placeholder will be set, and it will be selected by default.